# How to mark all lines of a block in vim line mode?

Tags: vim

I often find myself in a situation like this (Cursor position marked with `^`):

```
$a = [
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,^
    ],
    [
        'x' => 3,
    ];
];
```

I now want to delete the first inner `[` block so that I get:

```
$a = [
    [^
        'x' => 3,
    ];
];
```

This seems trivial, so my idea is:

- Enter **visual line** mode with <kbd>V</kbd>
- Mark all the lines in the `[`-block with <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- Delete it with <kbd>d</kbd>

But this does not work, because <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> seems to always implicity switch to **visual character** mode as if I started with <kbd>v</kbd> instead of <kbd>V</kbd>. So the result is an excessive line with a `,`:

```
$a = [
    ,^
    [
        'x' => 3,
    ];
];
```

This is very counterintuitive to me. Why does Vim think, it's smarter than me and forces character wise visual mode when I explicitely asked for line mode? And what is a simple (!!) way to get what I want (same number or fewer key strokes)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: (1) you can delete an enclosing `[...]` block without marking anything, with `da]`, and (2) if you need to do that kind of manipulation often you might take a look at writing a plugin for [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to not offer a solution with the same number of keystrokes or lower, only one with one character more:

Press <kbd>V</kbd> again to extend the selection to lines, i.e. `va[Vd`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does Vim think, it's smarter than me and forces character wise visual mode when I explicitely asked for line mode?

Because text-objects work at the character level, not the line level.

> And what is a simple (!!) way to get what I want (same number or fewer key strokes)?

```
va]:d<CR>
va]Vd
va]ddd
:-2,+d<CR>
```

Probably others. Map it to something easier if you find it cumbersome.

Comment: *Because text-objects work at the character level, not the line level.* - well, that describes what happens, but does not really answer the *why*. I think, if I explicitely ask for visual line mode, then Vim should never change that and try as hard as possible to stay in line mode. If I wanted character based mode, I'd have pressed `v` instead of `V` in the first place. Vim should not overrule my decision!

Comment: That decision was taken ages ago. If you want a precise explanation of the reasoning I'd suggest you peruse the mailing list archive or ask directly on the vim_dev mailing list. Or even create an issue on the issue tracker.